# Trouble looping over a dataframe and generating summary statistics

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, range, dataframe

I have a dataframe including a variable (t_seg_size) and I want to segment that variable into even segments e.g. 0-1000000, 1000001-2000000 etc.) and then generate summary statistics for each segment.

The method I'm using is to iterate over the dataframe in chunks of the appropriate size, then generate the stats such as .std().

Here is the code:

```
for x in range (1000000, 200000000, 1000000):
    print(df3[(x-999999 < df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())
```

---

So the loop should look for t_seg_size between (1) and (1000000) and generate the standard deviation. However, I receive the following error:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-ee3e9911be81> in <module>()
      2 #df3[df3["t_seg_size"] > 2000000].describe()
      3 for x in range (1000000, 200000000, 1000000):
----> 4     print(df3[(1000000 < df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())

C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    696         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    697                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 698                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    699 
    700     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want `print(df3[(df3["t_seg_size"] >= x-999999) &  (df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())` the error is highlighting the fact that comparing a scalar with an array is ambiguous, so to compare against an array you should use the bitwise operators `&` `|` `~` for `and` `or` `not` respectively, additionally the conditions need parentheses due to operator precedence

Comment: @EdChum many thanks for helping me again with my problems. 

If you have time, it would be great to know if there were any other ways of tackling this particular task - that is, splitting the dataframe according to certain ranges and generating stats.

+I also want to plot the summary stats as a graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error in this line:

```
print(df3[(x-999999 < df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())
```

is because it becomes ambiguous to compare a scalar with an array, because what if there is a single match or all but one match should it be `True`? To do this correctly you need to use the bitwise array operators `&`, `|` `~` for `and` `or` and `not` comparisons so this now becomes:

```
print(df3[(df3["t_seg_size"] >= x-999999) & (df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())
```

The parentheses are needed due to operator precedence.

To be honest what you're doing looks OK to me, not sure where you want to store the stats but you could just add this to a list, create a series/df from it and plot it:

```
stats={'range':[], 'std':[]}
for x in range (1000000, 200000000, 1000000):
    print(df3[(df3["t_seg_size"] >= x-999999) & (df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())
    stats['range'].append(x)
    stats['std'].append(df3[(df3["t_seg_size"] >= x-999999) & (df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())
```

you should be able to plot this using `pd.DataFrame(stats).plot()`

Comment: cool, but I get a syntax error for
    `stats={'range'=[], 'std'=[]}`
    `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Sorry should be `:` rather than `=`

Comment: the `.values[0]` is also unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to be very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous).
Try with [numpy.logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) it should solve the issue.

```
for x in range (1000000, 200000000, 1000000):
    print(df3[logical_and(df3["t_seg_size"] > x-999999, df3["t_seg_size"] < x)].t_seg_size.std())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion using `groupby` that should make it considerably faster:

```
 grouped = df.groupby((df.t_seg_size / 1000000).round())
 grouped.t_seg_size.std()
```

This will give you the standard deviation for each segment in a DataFrame in a fraction of the time. Another advantage is that you can call many other function on `grouped` once the grouping is done, such as mean, median etc. 
You can easily plot the result calling `.plot` on the result.